# No se ejecuta los eventos asociados a un botón

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un archivo PHP que me funciona como página principal el cual cuenta con algunas etiquetas HTML. Una de esas etiquetas es `button`, cuando me ha cargado la página se ejecuta un archivo JavaScript, el cual tiene algunas funciones entre esas los eventos de estas etiquetas.

Cuando presiono uno de esos botones me hace una petición al servidor, el cual me manda unos datos en formato JSON. Esos datos los manipulo agregándolos dentro de una tabla y agregándolos en etiquetas.

Uno de los datos que traigo del servidor lo meto dentro de una etiqueta `button`, la cual le agrego la clase "descargar" donde en el archivo JavaScript tengo un evento para esta clase.

El problema es que cuando presiono ese botón con la clase "descargar" no me activa el evento que le había asignado y es lo que no logro hacer funcionar. Mi pregunta es, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?
Archivo en PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["idcli"])) {
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/eventos.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <aside>
        <?php
        $id = $_SESSION["idcli"];
        require("conexion.php");
        $consulta = "SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, IMAGEN FROM clientes WHERE IDCLI=$id";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        $nfilas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
        if ($nfilas == 1) {
            while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                $nombre = $datos["NOMBRE"];
                $apellidos = $datos["APELLIDOS"];
                $imagen = $datos["IMAGEN"];
            }
            echo '<a href="#" id="img"><img src="' . $imagen . '" alt=""></a> ';
            echo '<a href="#" id="nombre">' . $nombre . " " . $apellidos . '</a>';
        }
        ?>

        <button class="btn" id="mcompras">Mis Compras</button>
        <button class="btn" id="productos">Productos</button>

    </aside>
    <header>
        <button id="cerrar">Cerrar Sesión</button>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div id="contenido"></div>
    </section>


</body>

</html>
```

archivo Javascript

```
 $("document").ready(function () {
    compras();
    $("button#productos").on("click", function () {
        productos();
    });
    $("button#mcompras").on("click", function () {
        compras();
    });
    $("button#cerrar").on("click", function () {
        location = "cerrar.php";
    });
    $("table  tr  td button.descargar").on("click", function () {
        console.log("prueba");
    });

});

function productos() {
    $("header h2").remove();
    $("header").prepend("<h2>PRODUCTOS</h2>");
    var a = "";
    a = "<table><tr><th>IMAGEN</th><th>NOMBRE</th><th>VIDEO</th><th>PRECIO</th><th>ACCIÓN</th></tr>";
    $.getJSON("productos.php", "", function (r) {
        for (var i in r) {
            a += "<tr class='datos'>"
                + "<td><img src='" + r[i].imagen + "'></td>"
                + "<td>" + r[i].nombre + "</td>"
                + "<td><a href='" + r[i].urlvideo + "' target='_blank'>Ver video</a></td>"
                + "<td>" + r[i].precio + "</td>"
                + "<td><button value='" + r[i].idpro + "' class='comprar'>Comprar</button></td>"
                + "</tr>";
        }
        a += "<table>";
        $("section > div#contenido").html(a);
    });

}
function compras() {
    $("header h2").remove();
    $("header").prepend("<h2>MIS COMPRAS</h2>");
    var a = "", b = 0;
    a = "<table><tr><th>IMAGEN</th><th>NOMBRE</th><th>VIDEO</th><th>ACCIÓN</th></tr>";
    $.getJSON("miscompras.php", "", function (r) {
        for (var i in r) {
            a += "<tr class='datos'>"
                + "<td><img src='" + r[i].imagen + "'></td>"
                + "<td>" + r[i].nombre + "</td>"
                + "<td><a href='" + r[i].urlvideo + "' target='_blank'>Ver video</a></td>"
                + "<td><button value='" + r[i].idpro + "' class='descargar'>Descargar</button></td>"
                + "</tr>";
            b++;
        }
        a += "<table>";
        $("section > div#contenido").html(a);
        if (b == 0) {
            $("section > div#contenido table").append("<p class='nocompras'>No existen compras registradas</p>");
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: La funcion de descarga , el evento no se encuentra en el DOM, por lo tanto hay que hacer esa funcion ahi fonde se recive la respuesta en JSON.

Comment: Veo el botón con la clase descargar pero en ningún lugar veo el evento clic para ese botón específicamente, estas seguro que si lo tiene?

Comment: Si, lo tiene, lo que pasa es que cuando subí el código estuve haciendo unas pruebas y se me olvidó dejarlo como era, ya he editado el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya han mencionado, el problema que tienes se debe a que creas el evento antes de que exista el botón en el DOM. Para prevenir este problema existen los *delegate events*, que delegan el evento a sus componentes *padres* y así, cuando se añade un elemento *hijo*, puede ejecutar el evento. No se si me he explicado del todo bien, pero todo se ve mejor con un ejemplo:

Esto es un evento normal de jQuery:

```
$(item).on('click', function()...
```

Esto es un evento delegate:

```
$(parent).on('click', item, function()...
```

Como ves, es muy sencillo. El evento actúa sobre el padre y se añade un nuevo parámetro al método `on()` para indicar cual será el hijo. En tu caso concreto, debería ser algo así:

```
$("table  tr  td").on("click", "button.descargar", function () {
    console.log("prueba");
});
```

**Info:**

https://api.jquery.com/on/

https://jqueryhouse.com/jquery-on-method-the-issue-of-dynamically-added-elements/

Comment: Hola @zeross, gracias por responder, remplace el codigo por lo que dijiste y no me funciono, sin embargo de acuerdo a tu explicacion deduci que como la tabla tampoco estaba creada anteriormente entonces debia tomar como referencia al padre de la tabla en este caso a div#contenido quedandome el codigo asi: $("div#contenido").on("click", "table tr td button.descargar", function () {console.log("prueba");
});

Answer (score 0):

Añado esto para complementar aunque ya esté resuelto el problema. En la versión de javascript puro el evento delegado se aplica al body del DOM y cualquier elemento dinámico creado a posteriori se podrá controlar analizando el target de ese click, con lo que hay que comprobar la propiedad que deseemos ya sea id, clase, etc.

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'btn-nuevo') {
       //acción a llevar a cabo.
    })
});
```